# Solve[..] does not solve the equation? A bug?

Tags: equation-solving

I tried to get the values of `CosTheta` where the `expression` is zero and store theses in `sol`.

```
expression = 
 CosTheta vecp (EMu^2 + me^2 - vecp^2) - Sqrt[
  EMu^2 ((EMu^2 - me^2)^2 - 
     2 (EMu^2 + (1 - 2 CosTheta^2) me^2) vecp^2 + vecp^4)]
sol = Solve[expression == 0, CosTheta]
expression /. sol[[1, 1]] // FullSimplify
expression /. sol[[2, 1]] // FullSimplify
```

But inserting them into the expression, this is never zero.
Where is the mistake?

I got

```
{{CosTheta -> -(EMu/vecp)}, {CosTheta -> EMu/vecp}}
```

and with these

```
-EMu (EMu^2 + me^2 - vecp^2) - Sqrt[EMu^2 (EMu^2 + me^2 - vecp^2)^2]
```

and

```
EMu^3 + EMu (me - vecp) (me + vecp) - Sqrt[
 EMu^2 (EMu^2 + me^2 - vecp^2)^2]
```

Comment: No mistake, just allowing for the square root to take the "other" value or for `EMu` to be negative or complex.

Comment: Your first answer is nonzero, but the second is zero.  Remove the squares from the square root by hand and you'll see that the expression exactly cancels.

Comment: But the first is not? Why?

Comment: This will further reduce things. `FullSimplify[expression /. sol, 
 Assumptions -> {EMu >= 0, me >= 0, vecp >= 0}]``. Note that in the presence of parameters, `Solve` will return solutions that might or might not be valid depending on values given to the parameters. That is, it cannot determine which might be parasites and which not.

Comment: @2012rcampion, @Matthias, the first root *is* (*can be*) zero. `Sqrt` of a positive number returns the positive root so if `EMu<0` the first solution is correct. Alternatively, though it is not Mathematica's default behavior, take positive `EMu` and take the other branch of `Sqrt` and get a solution again. Finally tell `Solve` to solve in the `Reals` domains and it will give big conditional expressions that shed light on the problem.

Comment: `Solve[expression == 0, CosTheta, MaxExtraConditions -> All]`

Comment: @belisarius, I find the output of your suggestion highly amusing. It reads "assuming the equation is satisfied, this is a solution" :-)